# Prevent all child component hooks and lifecycle method from executing when the parent components loads

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic4

I have a parent component which contains 3 child component. Only one child component is visible based on condition while the rest are hidden.
The problem is all lifecycle methods and hooks for every child component gets executed in the beginning when the parent page is loaded. I want when the child1 or child2 or child3 is visible then only its lifecycle methods and hooks should get executed. Please help. Thank you

````
  <div [hidden]="paginationHeaderNo != 0">
    <child1></child1>
  </div>
  <div [hidden]="paginationHeaderNo != 1">
    <child2></child2>
  </div>
  <div [hidden]="paginationHeaderNo != 2">
    <child3></child3>
  </div>
</ion-content>```
````

Answer (score 3):

You should use the structural directive `*ngIf`:

```
<div *ngIf="paginationHeaderNo === 0">
  <child1></child1>
</div>
```